# unable to replace text starting from *

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I had following code:-

```
      Time::Time(short y,short m,short d,short h,short mi,short s):
              (*this).y(y),
              (*this).m(m),
              (*this).d(d),
              (*this).h(h),
              (*this).mi(mi),
              (*this).s(s),   {};
```

I want to replace all `(*this).` with `this->`.
when I select the above code and use command `:%s/\%V(*this)./this->/g` as give [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace), I get following code:-

```
 Time::Time(short y,short m,short d,short h,short mi,short s):
          (*this->y(y),
          (*this->m(m),
          (*this->d(d),
          (*this->h(h),
          (*this->mi(mi),
          (*this->s(s),   {};
```

here is the needed result:-

```
 Time::Time(short y,short m,short d,short h,short mi,short s):
          this->y(y),
          this->m(m),
          this->d(d),
          this->h(h),
          this->mi(mi),
          this->s(s),     {};
```

I know that I can remove  `(*` manually but what if in future ,something like this but big text need to be replaced ?. that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to fix your regular expression

You need to "escape" the `*` character:

```
:%s/\%V(\*this)./this->/g
```

### What's going wrong

The `*` character in an regular expression means: zero or more of the preceding atom, matching as many as possible. (See `:help /star`)

You intend `(*this` in your expression to match the literal `(*this` in your text. Instead, it will match `this` or `(this` or `((this` or `(((this` etc.

Only the first of these (`this` not preceded by any brackets) exists in your text, so that is what the expression matches.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative without Regex

Not answering the question (about Regex), just hope this may help anyone.

OP mentioned

> when I select the above code in neovim and use command ...

If the block is selected, maybe a Block-Change command suits the situation more -- we have to type `this->` anyways. (With Block selection: `cthis-><Esc>` or `sthis-><Esc>`, but `s` is documented here instead... `:h visual-operators`)

Read more here: `:h blockwise-operators`.  Block Insert `I` and Append `A` are also quite useful sometimes.

By the way, if my cursor is at the `(` and I have to block-select all `(*this).`, probably I would by (wrong) instinct do `<C-v>www` (oh I have gone too far -- I just `w` for extend selection) and then `h` (to go back) and then `jjj`...

A better way to select them maybe `vab` (so you don't have to be at the start of the selection when you enter Visual mode) and then `<C-v>` (change to block selection mode) and do the rest `ljjj`...

Hope this helps someone -- I feel more comfortable if I don't have to use commands, especially pressing `:` in Visual mode needs `<C-u>` to clear the `'<,'>` -- and Regex are hard to type.

---

P.S. I am primarily a Perl dev and I worked with Regex everyday and when I use Regex in (n)vim mostly I'll use very magic so I'll have to escape *even* the `().`s... There are just too many Regex modes in Vim -- at least I've to be alert about all those characters. (Note the `\v` for `very magic`)

```
:%s/\%V\v\(\*this\)\./this->/g
```

In case you want a plain "replace", the `very nomagic` mode will have less margin for errors: (Because only the escaped ones have special meanings)

```
:%s/\%V\V(*this)./this->/g
```

Read more about the 4 Regex modes: `:h magic`

I only use the above 2 -- depending which has less to escape (Like `\V` for a lot of `()` in the string and `\v` for Perl-like regex functionality).